# Smoothness of a variety generically smooth along a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be variety over a field of characteristic zero and $D\subset X$ an irreducible Cartier divisor which is smooth.
Assume $X$ is smooth outside $D$ and generically smooth along $D$ (i.e. $\mathcal O_{X,\eta_D}$ is a DVR). Is it true that $X$ is smooth?

Comment: Are you assuming that $D$ is a Cartier divisor ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have edited the question

Comment: You say $D$ is regular, meaning smooth or something else ?

Comment: I could also have written $D$ smooth. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions (without the hypothesis on the generic point) imply smoothness. Here is a basic fact from commutative algebra. A local ring is regular if modulo a non-zero divisor in the maximal ideal, it is.